# How to access npm package event emitter client side in meteor

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, npm, browserify

I think this is pretty basic but am having trouble finding a solution. I have found an NPM package LOG-WATCHER (example only) that monitors a specific log file on a clients local file system. LOG-WATCHER emits events 'START', 'ACTION', 'END'. Since this file is client only I am using browserify. 
In my packages.json I have added
   `"LOG-WATCHER": "1.0"`

In /client/lib app.browserify.js I have added
    `logWatcher = require("LOG-WATCHER");`

logWatcher should now be a global variable that I can use in my app. So my question is how can I access one of the events START/ACTION/END through the logWatcher? Very confused on how to put into place.

Answer (score 0):

npmRequire is a funciton who presume you are on a NodeJs env. So you can use it only on Server.

Using browserify you will be able to create an assert for client. Take a look to this two links :
 - https://react-in-meteor.readthedocs.org/en/latest/meteor-data/
 - https://atmospherejs.com/cosmos/browserify

Comment: Thanks for the browserify mention. Do you know how to access the NPM packages events now that example is clarified?